# Translating sql query into Doctrine/dql

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

This is the query I want:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM counter ORDER BY id DESC) AS x GROUP BY campaign_id
```

but I can´t find a way to express this in my Symfony application. What is the correct way to use subqueries like this one in Doctrine?

This one:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT c
        FROM InstacountInstacountBundle:Counter c
        GROUP BY c.campaign');  
    $counts = $query->getResult();
```

is working fine, but I want only the latest records in my group. Thanks for any help!

Comment: This query doesn't make much sense. In general, in the absence of any aggregating functions, the use of GROUP BY is inappropriate. If you want DISTINCT results, use a DISTINCT operator. No need for any subqueries.

Comment: Can you show me an example, please?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT id, campaign_id FROM counter ORDER BY id DESC or perhaps SELECT MAX(id) id, campaign_id FROM counter GROUP BY campaign_id

Comment: These queries does not return what I want. I want campaign_id to be distinct values, and I want to pick the row with the highest id for every campaign_id. My first query in the post returns the result I want. The second query (in doctrine syntax) returns distinct values for campaign_id, but with the lowest id for that campaign_id. It's hard to explain, but I hope someone can understand what my problem is.

Comment: My second query definitely satisfies the requirement

Comment: I need the complete row with the highest id for a certain campaign_id. I can´t see your queries do that?

Comment: No. That's a different requirement. The correct answer for that is below.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM counter x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT campaign_id, MAX(id) max_id FROM counter GROUP BY campaign_id ) y
    ON y.campaign_id = x.campaign_id
   AND y.max_id = x.id;
```

Comment: When I try to write subqueries, I always get this error: "Error: Class '(' is not defined". Maybe this should work, but something must be wrong with the syntax.

Comment: I don't know anything about doctrine, but you can rewrite this query as follows, thus avoiding subqueries... SELECT x.* FROM counter x LEFT JOIN counter y ON y.campaign_id = x.campaign_id AND y.id < x.id WHERE y.id IS NULL; or something like that.